# unable to assume role after enforcing MFA policy

Tags: ansible, aws-sts, assume-role

I created a new policy to enforce IAM user to setup MFA using the policy in this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_my-sec-creds-self-manage.html

Now the IAM user has `AdministratorAccess` already..so now with applying this force MFA policy now the user has 2 policies attached. The AWS managed policy `AdministratorAccess` and the new Managed policy i created `Force_MFA`

now when i try to run ansible iwth module https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/sts_assume_role_module.html that normally worked before attaching the `Force_MFA` policy now i get error that says i can not assume role of other accounts.
When i remove the `Force_MFA` policy then it works again.

Where is the problem coming from. Is this issue with the policy or with ansible? Is this `Force_MFA` policy not working as expected? It supposed to let me do other things if MFA is enabled but in asnible it does not but in GUI i can switch roles and it works fine. Just that ansible playbooks now fail and complain i cant assume role.

Mind you i already enabled MFA for this IAM user and i can assume and switch accounts in dashboard BUT when i try to do that in ansible i get boto error saying i can not assume role

Any help will be appreciated.

If you need to post anything to help let me know and i will post.

Comment: (disclaimer: I am not familiar at all with your cloud provider, I just read the documentation). Since it seems you activated a feature to force Multi Factor Authentication, did you modify your `sts_assume_role` module call to integrate the `mfa_serial_number` and `mfa_token` options ?

Comment: i thought MFA is only for console login? yes i did see the mfa serial number an dtoken option for the sts_assume_role...never even realized those options exist...so thanks for bringing those up. yeah this MFA thing is a bit tricky because i thought ther are only meant for console login only..didnt realize it aks for mfa token even with cli in the case of ansible

Comment: yes you are right...i add to add `mfa_serial_number` and `mfa_token` options and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

According to comment made by @Zeitounator i add to add `mfa_serial_number` and `mfa_token` options as required for the `sts_assume_role` [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/sts_assume_role_module.html)

worked after that